# This placed the Clintons in the top 0.02 percent of US families

Tags: meaning, verbs, usage

I have a question about the usage of the verb "***place***" in this [article](https://www.wsws.org/en/articles/2016/08/13/taxe-a13.html):

> Bill and Hillary Clinton made $10.6 million in income in 2015, according to tax returns released by the Democratic presidential campaign Friday. This ***placed*** the Clintons in the top 0.02 percent of US families.

How does high incomes "***placed***" the Clintons in the top 0.02 percent of US families?  I check dictionaries and the closest definition that seems to work is definition 7 of this [dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/place_2):

> Def 7:  to decide that someone or something has a particular position or rank compared with other people or things

But this definition does not perfectly fit the usage in the article;  high incomes do not decide that the Clintons belong in the top 0.02 percent of US families.  What do native speakers think?

Comment: The fact that they made $ 10,6 million income  "placed" them in the top US families.

Comment: "high incomes do not decide that the Clintons belong in the top 0.02 percent of US families" - Yes they do; to phrase it a different way, high income is what decides whether the Clintons belong there.  "Decide" doesn't literally mean "sits down and considers the issue and then says, 'I have reached a conclusion'", it can mean slightly more loosely "is the deciding factor".

Comment: Compare: His amazing performance of scoring twelve goals in a single game **established him**  as the record-holder for goals in a single game.

Comment: @meatie: you're either on a mission to evaluate learner's dictionaries, or stubbornly refusing to use a dictionary more comprehensive than a learner's dictionary. Which is it?

Answer (score 3):

The definition you quoted suggests that placed is a matter of **deciding**, so you would expect to see a person as the subject.

> After examining video recordings, **officials** placed him joint second in the race.

It can also use to mean **indicating**, where the evidence is the subject.

> **Video evidence** placed him joint second in the race.

Similarly, you can say that somebody's IQ, income or whatever, indicates somebody's rank or position:

> His IQ of 145 places him in the top 1% of people in the United States [in terms of intelligence].
>
> The Clinton's tax returns placed them in the top 0.02 percent of US families [in terms of income].